# RPI use FQDN locally not .local

Tags: raspbian, dns

I would like to access my RPi on my local network by a FQDN that I have. Example: my home network can be reached at www.myhome.com and that in turn with port forwarding will reach my RPi internally at 192.168.1.100 (set statically in the router/RPi)

From internally I would like to reach the same RPi at its FQDN of rpi.myhome.com. Since the hostname = rpi and the static IP = 192.168.1.100 it seems like just adding to the /etc/hosts with the entry:
192.168.1.100 rpi.myhome.com
Should accomplish this. BUT... that's not the case. I can't seem to get around the problem that any hostname get the .local appended to it via the avahi deamon. So all local request end up as rpi.local.

I can set local DNS in my router I think, it's a Verizon FIOS router. But the problem of .local still exist.

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: The resolv.conf has my DNS IPs correct and the local FQDN already there so I don't think that's an issue - the nsswitch.conf I have no idea what that does?

Comment: Also try changing your `/etc/hostname` to `rpi.home.com` and do `hostname -F /etc/hostname` and then reboot

Comment: `nsswitch.conf` file is used for you name service configuration. Try `man nsswitch.conf` to get more details

Comment: have tried renaming hostname: rip.home.com and cannot resolve dns, tried to ping rpi.home.com and timeout - not sure where DNS is taking place - hosts file is set to 192.168.1.100 rpi.home.com so I don't think its there ? Have also setup DNS server in router for local IPs and still no resolution.

Comment: Another issue I'm finding: on the RPi box, if I go to http://127.0.0.1 the browser URL always shows "raspberry.local" - I don't think this is cached, so where is it still getting this from?

Comment: try adding your dns next to your loopback address `127.0.0.1 rpi rpi.home.com` this might be the thing too

Comment: i the syntax correct with: `127.0.0.1 rpi rpi.home.com` or should it be `127.0.0.1 rpi.home.com`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56423/discussion-between-shan-desai-and-barclayvision).